# Retrieve QComboBox index from QCompletion popup

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QComboBox` with a `QCompleter`. The `QCompleter` displays suggestions in a popup list and I'm drawing the elements in a custom way.

The problem is: I can't get the index in the original combobox even if I did store it into the `UserData` of the item.

Complete code follows:

```
class MyItemDelegate: public QItemDelegate {
public:
    MyItemDelegate(QWidget *parent) :
      QItemDelegate(parent) {}

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
               const QModelIndex &index ) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        if (index.row() == 0) { // If this is the first item in the POPUP VIEW

          auto comboIndex = index.data(Qt::UserRole).toInt();
          qDebug() << "Combobox index is " << comboIndex; // WRONG!!
        }
       ... custom styling code omitted since off-topic ...
    }
};

MyWindow::MyWindow(QStringList words, QMainWindow *parent) :
  QDialog((QWidget*)parent),
  ui(new Ui::MyWindow) {

  ui->setupUi(this);

  int comboBoxIndex = 0;
  for(auto& word : words) {
    ui->myComboBox->addItem(word, comboBoxIndex); // This is stored in UserData
    ++comboBoxIndex;
  }

  completer = new QCompleter(words, this);

  // Use a TreeView for the popup of the completer
  QTreeView *treeView = new QTreeView(this);
  completer->setPopup(treeView);

  treeView->setItemDelegate(new MyItemDelegate(this));
}
```

No matter what element I have first in the `QCompletion` popup list, the `qDebug()` line always returns `0` as index.

Isn't `index.data()` referring to the original item data of the combobox?

Answer (score 0):

As i see, your problem is that you retrieve `comboIndex` from model where you didn't set `UserData`. You set `UserData` for items of internal `QComboBox` model (see [QComboBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html)), but when you try to retrieve this data, you do that in code of `MyItemDelegate`, which you set for `QTreeView` for `QCompleter`. That's why `index` in `paint` method of delegate is index of `QCompleter` internal model, not index of `QComboBox` internal model. And that's why `comboIndex` is always `0`.

To solve your problem you can add `UserData` in `QCompleter` internal model. For example, you can create your own model and set this model for `QCompleter` with method [setModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#setModel).